# Extend theme css Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, luma-theme

I have created a theme in which i have extended luma theme. Now in my new theme I want to add some custom css to overwrite some default css classes for that I added _extend.less inside

> test/luma/web/css/source.

Inside _extend.less i added some classes like

```
.logo {  display:none; }
```

I haven't added styles-l.less and styles-m.less inside my theme and default_head_block.xml.

Now when I run commands

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

and then after cleaning cache

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

my rules are not implemented and default css breaking too.

Please suggest me the solution..

Answer (score 0):

1) Go to `app/design/frontend/text/luma/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml` and add this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../vendor/magento/framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/custom.css" />
    </head>
</page>
```

2) add your **css** file in `app/design/frontend/test/luma/web/css/custom.css`

3) clean cache : `php bin/magento cache:flush`
                 `php bin/magento cache:clean`

**Edit:**
If you want to extend **css** from a `parent theme`, you have to create `_extend.less` in `web/css/source`

Now to add you changes on it, you create the file less that you want to change it for exemple :  `_navigation_extend.less`, you add you changes then you declare it in `_extend.less`like this: `@import '_navigation_extend.less';`

for more informations, check this [Magento DevDocs.](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-guide/css_quick_guide_approach.html)

Comment: it there any way to extend styles-l and styels-m because if i add css using this way then my css will be above than magento css and it will overwrite my rules

Comment: Please, Look my update

Comment: I tried this i added _extend.less and then added a class like .logo{display:none;} but it doesn't affect anything. I deployed static content as well. but still there was no change. m i missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason your styles are not showing up is that you aren't clearing the `var/view_preprocessed` folder when you recompile. The `var/view_preprocessed` is a cached version of the front-end files that Magento will draw from when the files in the `pub` are not there. So it can be a little maddening and counterintuitive when updating styles on a site.

You have the correct files in the correct places, but when you make a change in your less files you only have to remove the style files in `pub/static` folder, clear `var/view_preprocessed`, remove the cache with  `php bin/magento cache:clean` and then reload the page. There is no need to run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`, that only needs to be run when you are updating the version of a module. It removes some directories and so might seem like it's working for you, but it's a waste of time for changing CSS.

Comment: Ok i have created a new theme which is child of luma theme. i have created theme.xml and registration.php now inside web/css/source folder. I have created _extend.less then inside that file i have written a css rule like.
.logo{ display: none} after running upgrade command and deployed static content that rule still not coming. i cleared var/view_preprocessed folder before running those commands. did i do something wrong

Comment: no, those are the correct steps. Like i said, you don't have to run the upgrade command. I can't think of anything for sure that would be an error. I'm assuming you have set the theme in the admin?

Comment: Yes I have set that theme from admin and I have enabled developer mode too. When I import my custom less in _theme.less and then deploy the static content it gives me some variable error in style-l.less and I haven't included styles-l in my new theme.

Comment: what is the error? These files in the `pub` folder are compiled from all the less in Magento. So it could be an error in another file, or something in your file that just isn't playing nice (like a missing semicolon or closing bracket).